# Spring Session JDBC - How to catch when the session is destroyed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

Since Spring Session JDBC implementation does not support publishing of session events, how can I catch when the session is destroyed? I need to perform some additional logic when user's session has ended, but I couldn't find any other workaround. In the Spring Session docs there isn't any other solution presented.

Comment: Hi, Vlad. Share please a code snippet. And what kind of additional logic do you want to add?

Comment: Spring closes a session when the transaction commits/rollbacks, or even later. Read about transaction management, I think you may try to implement a custom TransactionManager, where you can catch commit and rollback events.

Comment: Hi Ilya, thank you for the fast reply. I'm trying to catch when there is explicit logout by the user and when the user session has expired. In both cases I need the sessionId because I need to keep track when the user logged out and why. There is separate table in which I keep track of each session, it acts as some kind of audit.

I was thinking to override deleteById method in SessionRepository and add this part there? Is that possible?